# Trigger 10 minutes after (MySql)

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-event

```
name_id(INT)(PRIMARY)   name(VARCHAR(50))   add_time(DATETIME)
        1                    stuff         2015-10-22 10:55:41
        2                    stuff         2015-11-25 14:54:20
```

I have table `main` as shown. User can add new stuff into this table.I want a trigger event that:

> runs 10 minutes after the new row has been added into `main`
>
> gets `name_id` for that new `name`

I now i need a `MySql Event` rather than a `trigger` since i want to wait 10 minutes. However i couldn't understand how i am gonna trigger this new event for a specific row rather than a whole table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trigger as usual but first call the [sleep](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) function, providing the number of seconds to sleep for (600 in your case) as an argument.